# what is the integral of this expression?

Tags: integration

What is the integral of this expression ?.
Can you show me the calculation process ?.
Thanks very much.

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left[1 - \left(1 - u\right)^{\kappa}\right]^{-1/\gamma}\,{\rm d}u
$$

Comment: What happens when you raise an expression to the $-\gamma$ power, and then to the $-1/\gamma$ power? How do those two exponents interact?

Comment: sorry, I revised it.

Comment: Sorry, I revised it before you put your revision in. Is it all fixed now?

Comment: yes, it is fixed. thanks.

Comment: Do you know anything about the constants? Are they rational for example?

Comment: I just know the parameter is $k$ and $r$, and I want to get the integral with parameter $k$ and $r$.

Comment: Please do not radically alter your question after it has already been answered (especially since you already [asked the new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814385/can-someone-compute-the-integral-of-this-expression)). I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - \pars{1 - u}^{\kappa}}^{-1/\gamma}\,\dd u:\
     {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{
> \int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - \pars{1 - u}^{\kappa}}^{-1/\gamma}\,\dd u}
> =\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - u^{\kappa}}^{-1/\gamma}\,\dd u
> =\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - u}^{-1/\gamma}\,{1 \over \kappa}\,u^{1/\kappa - 1}
> \,\dd u
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \kappa}\,\underbrace{{\rm B}\pars{-\,{1 \over \gamma} + 1,{1 \over \kappa}}}_{\ds{\mbox{Beta Function}}} 
> ={1 \over \kappa}\,\underbrace{%
> {\Gamma\pars{-1/\gamma + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/\kappa} \over \Gamma\pars{1/\kappa - 1/\gamma + 2}}}_{\ds{\Gamma:\ \mbox{Gamma Functions}}}\,,\qquad \kappa > 0\,,\quad \pars{~\gamma < 0\quad \mbox{or}\quad \gamma > 1~}
> \end{align}

Comment: thanks very much for your help! could help to compute the integral above again? I just revised it. Thanks.

Comment: @eric You're welcome.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Marin, i proposed the whole question. Could please compute the whole integral again? Thanks very much for your help!http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814385/can-someone-compute-the-integral-of-this-expression?noredirect=1#comment1683148_814385