# Can someone compute the integral of this expression?

Tags: integration

Backgroud:
I want to compute the kendalls' tau of SJC copula function. but I do not know how to compute its integral. One part of the integral is as follows:

Can someone compute the integral of this expression?
Can you show me the whole calculation process?.
Thanks very much.

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left[\left[1 - \left(1 - u\right)^{\kappa}\right]^{-\gamma}+\left[1- \left(1 - v\right)^{\kappa}\right]^{-\gamma}\right]^{-1/\gamma}{\rm d}u
$$

Comment: So ... is this your homework?  Looks like it.  If not, why not tell us more about the problem?

Comment: it is part of my research.I want to compute the kendalls' tau of SJC copula function,but I forget how to compute the integral, so I ask for help...

Comment: Is $v$ a constant?  Or some function of $u$?

Comment: $v$ is a constant

Comment: sorry, could you help me? thanks.

Comment: Say more about the constants.  For example, is $v\le 1$?  Is $\kappa > 0$?  And so on...

Comment: In case $\kappa=2, \gamma=1$, Maple evaluates this using arctangent.  In case $\kappa=2, \gamma=2$, Maple says it is an elliptic integral, and Maple's answer is ten screens long.

Comment: sorry for so late. the $k>0$,$r<0$. could tell me the basic logic? I just don't know how to compute it.